# Not able to train the Deepspeech model on Windows

Tags: python, speech-recognition, training-data, mozilla-deepspeech

I have tried to train Deepspeech model on Windows, as I can not use Linux. But, I am not able to train I am getting error

````
  File "E:/deepspeech-german-master/DeepSpeech/training/deepspeech_training/train.py", line 30, in <module>
    from DeepSpeech.native_client.ctcdecode import ctc_beam_search_decoder, Scorer
  File "E:\deepspeech-german-master\DeepSpeech\native_client\ctcdecode\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import swigwrapper # pylint: disable=import-self
ImportError: cannot import name 'swigwrapper' from 'DeepSpeech.native_client.ctcdecode' (E:\deepspeech-german-master\DeepSpeech\native_client\ctcdecode\__init__.py)```

I installed Kenlm language model using cygwin. But I am not able to train. If anybody has used it on windows. Can you please help, I am stuck on this since back so many days.
````

Answer (score 1):

[Swig](https://swig.org) is a build and packaging tool. It is not pre-built for Windows which is why you are receiving the `swigwrapper` error. You can [read more about running Swig on Windows here](http://swig.org/Doc4.0/Windows.html).

A much better approach to running DeepSpeech on Windows is to install Docker, and use a Docker environment for training. This removes a lot of the dependency issues you are facing. This is [documented in the DeepSpeech PlayBook](https://mozilla.github.io/deepspeech-playbook/ENVIRONMENT.html).